# How to correctly construct path to local folder when scp from remote to local

Tags: linux, console, digital-ocean, scp

I'm trying to download a file from my remote server on DigitalOcean, to my local machine on Windows. I haven't been able to figure out how to correctly specify the path to my local destination without getting a "No such file or directory" error. My Windows user is "Firstname Lastname" and some error messages seem to indicate that it doesn't know how to handle the space in the name. This questions has been asked multiple times, but they all use example paths. Here are some example I have tried to do not work:

- user@ipaddress:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/akd/css/overwrite.css C:/Users/Firstname Lastname/Desktop
- C:/Users/FirstnameLastname/Desktop
- /Users/Firstname Lastname/Desktop
- Users/Firstname Lastname/Desktop

Does anyone know the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why you don't use your local machine to access and download the file from server?
You can use something like this:
scp -P 2025 root@your_ip:/var/www/file.zip .